# invited friends do not receive invitations from my facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-requests

I'm trying to let the users of my app (which is still under development, i.e. Site URL still http://localhost:portnumbber, but sandbox mode is Disabled) to send invitations for the app using the URL like the following:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=1234567890&message=MY%20Message&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1234/page.aspx

when i click on the link and send invitations i got no errors. the problems that i have is that when i check the test-users that i've created for testing purposes i can see no invitation to any app. but what i've noticed that when i login in to the test-user account (in facebook) i see number one up on the small notifications icon, then it disappears immediately and automatically, and when i search for any invitations in the test-user account i don't find anything ... is this because i'm still using localhost:portnumbber in the Site URL in the app configuration and setting page in facebook ? or did i miss configure something in the app setting ?